# 14.04 can't get Epson ME-103 scanner to work

Tags: software-installation, scanner, epson

I got a brand new computer and would like to use Ubuntu 64 bit  tried  13.10 for a month and got stuck with getting my Epson ME-301 scanner to work. Now 14.04 is released, I gave another try but did not succeed.

First checked at SANE project that my printer is supported by epson2,

I followed the instructions guiding me to epson [download center](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule)

and got the drivers for both the printer and scanner i.e.

`epson-inkjet-printer-201204w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb`  this didn't work.

`epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.4.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb`   this got the printer to print

I installed the scanner files in the below sequence .. data, iscan by double clicking the deb file

```
 iscan-data_1.27.0-1_all.deb
 iscan_2.29.3-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_amd64.deb
 iscan-network-nt-*.*.*-*.amd64.deb
```

Didn't work

Read the Ubuntu help page [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SANE%20-%20Installing%20a%20scanner%20that%20isn%27t%20auto-detected)

Edit the file /etc/sane.d/dll.conf

```
run sudo sane-find-scanner
found USB scanner (vendor=0x0bda [Generic], product=0x0129 [USB2.0-CRW]) at libusb:002:005
```

run `sudo scanimage -L`

```
device `epkowa:usb:002:002' is a Epson ME-301/XP-200 Series flatbed scanner
device `epkowa:usb:002:005' is a Epson (unknown model) flatbed scanner
```

read the man page of`sane-usb`, `sane-epkowa`, `sane-epson2`

```
sudo gedit /etc/sane.d/dll.conf to uncomment (remove the # in front of usb)
sudo gedit /etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf and epson2.conf to enter the line usb Vendor product number from sane-find-scanner
```

used `xsane 0.998` frontend
after a long pause there is a device selection page
CLicked OK and it showed

`failed to open device 'epkowa:usb:002:005: Access to resouce has been denied`

used simple scan
nothing moved

I'm getting desperate and feel bad about trying to switch to Ubuntu from windows. It sucked weeks of my time and still can't get the scanner going. Otherwise it'll be a perfect switch. Maybe I'll try dual booting next.

Really would appreciate any help to get my Epson ME-301 scanner to work

Comment: How are you trying to connect? Via USB? Over the network?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect over wi-fi, you might try the instructions [here](http://download.ebz.epson.net/faq/linux/faq_ls_00007.html).

Specifically, after installing the Epson drivers, you should edit /etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf to include network devices (there are instructions in the file). Then you should be sure to comment out the conflicting "epson" and "epson2" lines in /etc/sane.d/dll.conf